# Guarantees about the lifetime of a reference in a local variable

Tags: swift, class, automatic-ref-counting

In *Swift*, I can use the *ARC* mechanism to manage the lifetime of resources external to the process because instances of classes are de-initialized predictably. This is in contrast to environments like the *Java* Runtime where instances are de-initialized when the garbage collector collects the object, which is not guaranteed to happen in a defined time window.

But what are the exact guarantees that the Swift language and runtime make about the lifetime of instances when those instances are referenced by local variables? E.g. what is the earliest point that an instance may be deallocated, when a local variable is holding the only reference to it?

In the following example, I am creating an instance of a class and store a reference to it in a local variable.

```
public final class Something {
    init() { print("something.init()") }
    deinit { print("something.deinit()") }
}

func useSomething() {
    let something = Something()
    print("useSomething()")
}

useSomething()
```

The variable is not used after the point where I print `useSomething()` but `deinit` runs consistenly *after* that call to `print()`:

```
$ swift run -c release
something.init()
useSomething()
something.deinit()
```

It seems that references are always decremented at the point where the variable goes out of scope. Wrapping the variable declaration in a `do` block changes the order:

```
func useSomething() {
    do { let something = Something() }
    print("useSomething()")
}
```

```
$ swift run -c release
something.init()
something.deinit()
useSomething()
```

Is this order guaranteed or can it change with a different compiler or optimization level?

---

The reason I'm interested in this is that I want to wrap C APIs in object-oriented Swift APIs and would like to automatically manage the lifetime of resources allocated using a C API using Swift classes and reference counting. This works great if every usage of the C API requires a reference to the resource it operates on because I know that the Swift instance will live at least until the last call that operates on the resource that instance is representing.

But some APIs use global state to select a resource and subsequent calls to the API do not require a reference to the resource to be passed and implicitly operate on the selected resource instead. OpenGL's `glDrawElements()` implicitly uses maybe 5 or 10 such resources (vertex arrays, shaders, frame buffers, textures …).

Comment: `glDrawElements` uses those resources but I am pretty sure that you are not required to retain them in memory. They are already stored in the open gl context, or even in GPU memory. I am pretty sure that you are trying to solve a problem that does not really exist.

Comment: @Sulthan I haven't gone into detail very much about how this applies to the example of OpenGL's API because that's not the point of my question but I an very positive that I am solving a real problem here. E.g. my `class GLVertexArray`'s `deinit` contains a call to `glDeleteVertexArrays()`. If that call happens too early, the vertex array will be unbound and destroyed and the resources in the OpenGL context (e.g. in the graphics card's memory) will be released before I am done using them, which is a bad thing.

Comment: I think I understand but the answer to that problem is not to inspect when `deinit` is called. The answer is that you need to store a strong reference to everything you need otherwise it could have been deallocated already. There is a reason why OpenGL have a separate `glDeleteVertexArrays` call. If you are putting that into `deinit`, you need to hold the reference to that class.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://forums.swift.org/t/arc-precise-lifetime-semantics/918/3 .

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you for your comment. Again, how to interact with OpenGL is not the point of this question. I am very well aware of what calls to the OpenGL API have to happen when. My question is about what guarantees I get from the Swift runtime so that I can use it's features without writing non-portable code that breaks with a different compiler, version or setting.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the reference. The link in that post is since broken. I assume it would have pointed to this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift makes no guarantee about the the lifetime of an object until
the end of the closest surrounding scope, see for example
the following threads in the Swift Forum:

- [Should Swift apply “statement scope” for ARC](https://forums.swift.org/t/should-swift-apply-statement-scope-for-arc/4081)
- [ARC // Precise Lifetime Semantics](https://forums.swift.org/t/arc-precise-lifetime-semantics/918)

where it is stated you can use [`withExtendedLifetime(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime):

> Evaluates a closure while ensuring that the given instance is not destroyed before the closure returns.

for that purpose. As for the rationale,
[Dave Abrahams (Apple)](https://forums.swift.org/t/should-swift-apply-statement-scope-for-arc/4081/8) states:

> The lack of such a guarantee, which is very seldom actually useful
> anyhow, is what allows us to turn costly copies (with associated
> refcount traffic and, often CoW allocation and copying fallout) into
> moves, which are practically free. Adopting it would basically kill our
> performance story for CoW.

And [Joe Groff (Apple)](https://forums.swift.org/t/should-swift-apply-statement-scope-for-arc/4081/2) in the same thread:

> Yeah, if you want to vend resources managed by an object to consumers outside of that object like this, you need to use withExtendedLifetime to keep the object alive for as long as you're using the resources. A cleaner way to model this might be to put the class or protocol in control of handling the I/O to the file handle, instead of vending the file handle itself, so that the ownership semantics fall out more naturally:

**Update (Jan 2022):** It is currently being discussed whether or not to introduce lexical lifetimes for objects. For the details, see [A roadmap for improving Swift performance predictability: ARC improvements and ownership control](https://forums.swift.org/t/a-roadmap-for-improving-swift-performance-predictability-arc-improvements-and-ownership-control/54206) in the Swift forum.

Comment: The referenced thread pretty much explains what I can expect from the compiler regarding lifetime of reference types. This brought to my attention that I actually never witnessed that behaviour, which lead me to [my next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986455/swift-class-de-initialized-at-end-of-scope-instead-of-after-last-usage).