# Swift class de-initialized at end of scope instead of after last usage

Tags: swift, class, automatic-ref-counting

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974241/guarantees-about-the-lifetime-of-a-reference-in-a-local-variable?noredirect=1#comment84954523_48974241) asking *about the guarantees of the lifetime of a reference in a local variable* and was referred to [this thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/should-swift-apply-statement-scope-for-arc/4081) in which *the exact semantics of the lifetime of references to class instances* were discussed. AFAICT from that thread, a class instance may be de-initialized right after the last usage of a variable containing the last reference, even before other expressions in the same statement are evaluated. It is argued there that allowing this behavior is necessary to prevent creating unnecessary copies in copy-on-write data structures, which I can follow.

This brought to my attention that up to now I've never seen Swift behave in that manner. Whenever I traced the execution, whether in a debug or release build, class instances were only initialised when leaving a complete scope.

In the following example in `main()`, I create an instance of a class which prints to the console during its lifecycle. Note that the instance is not used during or after the call to `print()` in `main()`:

```
public final class Something {
    init() { print("Something.init()") }
    deinit { print("Something.deinit") }
}

func main() {
    let something = Something()
    print("in main()")
}

main()
```

When building and running this example with the debug or release configuration, I see the following order of execution, i.e. the instance is kept alive during the call to `print()` in `main()`:

```
$ swift run -c release
Something.init()
in main()
Something.deinit
```

Instead, I would have expected the following order of execution:

```
$ swift run -c release
Something.init()
Something.deinit
in main()
```

I am using the Swift compiler 4.0.3 distributed with Xcode 9.2:

```
$ swift --version
Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

How can this order of execution be explained, considering that the developers of the Swift compiler are trying to be very agressive with decrementing ARC reference counters (and this de-initializing class instances) to avoid unnecessary copies in copy-on-write data structures? Is there some other optimization at play here because in this case keeping the reference alive does not actually lead to unnecessary work (just memory being allocated for longer than strictly necessary)?

My question is not about solving a particular issue I have, after all the compiler is creating code that is well withing the bounds of what the language allows. I would like to get a good understanding of how the Swift compiler is treating references and what optimizations are at play so that I can gauge which code patterns lead to good performance in critical situations, e.g. when large data structures would need to be copied by copy-on-write or when a large number of references are involed which need to be incremented and decremented.

Comment: Why would you expect the instance to be deinitialized before the end of the function scope? The variable `something` holds a strong reference to the `Something` instance, so until the end of function scope (where `something` is declared), the reference count of that instance is 1, so it cannot be deinitialized.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thank you for your comment. Please read the thread in the swift.org forums (2nd link in the question). According to the statements of the developers there, the compiler is free to deallocate an instance as soon as it's no longer possible to access it. There is no reference to the variable `something` in or after the call to `print()` so it's not possible to access the instance at that point. This is my understanding of what is written in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analize how Swift works is respect to memory management:

1. an object is deallocated when no are no more strong references to it
2. a variable is "destroyed" when the scope where it's declared ends

Given the above two above facts, your `Something` instance is kept alive by the `something` variable which holds a strong reference to it until the end of scope, i.e. until the `main` function returns.

Try replacing `let something = Something()` by `_ = Something()` and you see that the expected behaviour that you want:

```
Something.init()
Something.deinit
in main()
```

Same behaviour occurs when holding a weak reference to the instance: `weak var something = Something()`

Note that there is a slight difference here between the `something` variable and the `Something` instance. The variable holds a **reference** to the instance, not the instance itself. Thus, the reference lifetime is the same as the variable lifetime, and this is what affect the instance's lifetime. Why the variable is not destroyed sooner, e.g. when the compiler detects it's no longer needed, I don't know.

Comment: Point 2 in your answer contradicts my understanding of the thread on `forums.swift.org` linked in my question. Isn't the behaviour you described implying that code like `var a = [1]; var b = a; b[0] = 2` is required to create a copy of the array, because the variable `a` is still alive while `b` is modified, even though that copied value in `a` is never going to be used? This contradicts my understanding of performance characteristics the Swift developers are trying to achieve (i.e. minimise unnecessary copying).

Comment: @Feuermurmel what you describe above is copy-on-write. Also note that there's a slight difference between a variable and the contents it holds. In the `Something` case from the question, the variable is holding a reference that disappears along with the variable, and that's the one that keeps the object alive until the end of the function.

Comment: But thanks for the example with assigning to `_` which shows different behaviour. Can you provide some reference to where this "destroying" of variables, and its connection to reference counting, is described? From my understanding of the linked thread, the designers of the Swift language are of the opinion that the compiler should be free to deallocate instances as soon as accessing it is no longer possible.

Comment: @Feuermurmel the decision to deallocate an object is taken at runtime, what the compiler can do is to insert the proper retain/release calls, in a manner that shortens as much as possible the lifetime of an object while ensuring data integrity within the application.

Comment: Your code sample is trivial, more complicated scenarios would involve passing the instance around, and the compiler cannot tell which how many strong references will that object receive. This is different for value types, as their lifetime is tied to the variable that refers them. Reference types can outlive the variable that declared them.

Comment: the compiler should be free to deallocate instances as soon as accessing it is no longer possible - the keyword is *possible*, i.e. in your example, it would be *possible* to access something, hence it is not deallocated until main() terminates.

in the _ = Something() case, it is impossible to access that instance of Something as soon as the next line, hence the instance is deallocated almost immediately.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48

Comment: @Marcpek what if the `print()` call would've been `print("something: \(something)")`, how would've the compiler know if the instance should be no longer accessible or not?

Comment: I was citing verbatim, yes the decision is taken at runtime, I was just wondering whether there was a misunderstanding over what *possible to access* meant

Comment: @Marcpek To clarify, with _possible to access_ I mean _there is a codepath which the compiler must assume can still be taken and which accesses the instance_. Thus, with my wording, in my example, it is _not possible_ to access the instance of `Something` on or after the line `print("in main()")` (there is no reference to that variable anywhere).

Comment: @Cristik "… how would've the compiler know if the instance should be no longer accessible or not". What do you mean by that question? I think that the compiler can figure that out by looking at the code?

Comment: @Feuermurmel well, you pass an instance to the `print` function, in order for the compiler to know if `print` will hold a strong reference to that instance it must inspect the binary where `print` lives, and if `print` forwards the instance to another function in another module, then to inspect the other module, and so on.

Comment: @Cristik Oh, ok. Now I see where you're getting at. Ok. Of course there are may things I implicitly take for granted when making such statements. Even if I could count them all up, they could never fit in a comment here. For example, I was implicitly assuming that the compiler only looks at the code it actually compiles (a file or a whole module, depending on mode). And I would assume the compiler to do the analysis only to some extend, depending on the compile time <-> runtime tradeoff being made by the compiler's developers.

Comment: @Cristik But in this trivial example I would assume the compiler to look at all of those 2 lines of code to determine after which point it is _no longer possible_ to access the instance through the variable `something`.

Comment: @Feuermurmel in the end the discussion is what keeps the instance alive, and that is the strong reference from the variable. I've added a new paragraph to the response try to better explain this.

Comment: @Cristik Ok. So that's what I meant. IMHO there is no reason for the variable to be kept "alive" during or after the call to `print()`. And I'm interested to why this is happening. I do not really buy the concept of "variable lifetime" because that's not how a compiler works internally. A compiler e.g. has to decide what data should be kept in registers and what is pushed to the stack. It can minimise pushing data to the stack by reordering code and overwriting data that is provably no longer needed, as long as the behaviour is within that prescribed by the specification.

Comment: @Feuermurmel it could be that object references get a special treatment in order to avoid data corruption

Comment: @Feuermurmel I see what you mean, those posts say that Swift ARC normally releases objects as soon as they are no longer referenced, whereas in my experience (and in your example) instances are released when they fall out of scope. Maybe the former behaviour takes place when one uses manual memory management mixed in with Swift ARC or with another optimisation. As I see it, the compiler inserts a retain(something) when assigning, and puts a corresponding release(something) when the scope falls out. If the number of references left is 0, the runtime releases the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you had made your variable an optional and set it to nil, you would have explicitly told the compiler where you want the reference to be released.

e.g.

```
func main() {
    var something:Something? = Something()
    something = nil
    print("in main()")
}
```

Otherwise you are letting the compiler decide execution order on its own. In the same way that it could decide to execute any line of code out of order, it can also decide when to deallocate local variables.

In your example "something" is an non-optional local variable, so it is likely that the compiler will decide to allocate it on the stack. This  will mean that the variable's value (on the stack) will hold the reference until the function returns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Did you mean to write _In this case "something" is an **optional** local variable_?

Comment: I actually meant non-optional but I realize that, because of the example I  placed above that statement, it because ambiguous.  I reordered the paragraphs to avoid the confusion.