# Swift and RAII: deinit behavior inconsistent between project and playground

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

Let me preface the question by stating that I've read through everything in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986455/swift-class-de-initialized-at-end-of-scope-instead-of-after-last-usage) and the [documentation for ARC](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

I'm trying to use the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) idiom to handle a problem and am running into some inconsistencies that are preventing it from working.

This is an example that demonstrates the inconsistency:

```swift
class TestClass {
    init() {
        print("init")
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

func test() {
    TestClass()
    defer { print("defer") }
    print("end of scope")
}

test()
```

From my c++ experience I expected the deinit of the `TestClass` instance to happen at the end of the `test` function scope, and this is the behavior I wanted for what I'm trying to do.

At the same time I realize I'm initializing an instance of `TestClass` but not storing it in a variable, so there is no strong reference to it and for that reason it makes sense for it to be deallocated right away.

So the problem and question arises because this behavior is not consistent between projects and playgrounds.

In a playground, the above code produces the following output:

```
init
end of scope
defer
deinit // deinit happens at end of scope
after scope
```

But in a project the exact same code produces this different result:

```
init
deinit // deinit happens immediately
end of scope
defer
after scope
```

So

1. Why does this behave differently between projects and playgrounds?
2. Is there a way to control/guarantee which behavior will be used in a project? I want the playground behavior if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playgrounds are compiled differently – unlike a regular compile, the compiler transforms your code by [inserting various calls to instrumentation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5acd5e65c496e53a635ff2c4957a846c250d877e/lib/Sema/PlaygroundTransform.cpp). This lets you, for example, see what expressions evaluate to. However it can have the unfortunate side-effect of changing how your program behaves.

It's worth noting however that unlike languages like C and C++, Swift doesn't guarantee that local variables (or in your case, values from unused expressions) will remain valid until the end of the scope in which they're defined. The optimiser is free to deinitialise them earlier.

If you want to guarantee the lifetime of `SomeClass` in your example, you can use [`withExtendedLifetime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime):

```
func test() {
  withExtendedLifetime(TestClass()) {
    defer { print("defer") }
    print("end of scope")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Playgrounds make all kinds of references to objects for the purposes of displaying them in the sidebar and result previews.

You should consider the playground's strong references as totally indeterministic. For any real lifetime debugging, you need to run your code in a standalone program, library, etc.